# Excel: Creating list by removing "False" records

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following table:

```
19-Nov  TRUE
18-Nov  FALSE
17-Nov  TRUE
16-Nov  FALSE
15-Nov  TRUE
14-Nov  TRUE
13-Nov  TRUE
```

I want to create a new column that removes the false records - e.g.

```
19-Nov
17-Nov
15-Nov
etc.
```

Is there a way to do this **without using VBA** ? I already have a lot of VBA action going on in my document, and I would prefer to just use a string of formulas.

I researched this topic but only found examples using VBA.

Thank you all for the help

Comment: You cannot delete rows with Excel formulas. Is that what you want to do ?

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur No, sorry, I want to create a new column that only includes those observations that have a corresponding "TRUE" - does that make sense?

Comment: Could you perhaps just create a pivot table that has one column containing dates and filter it so it contains only the true values? You can hide the filter if you don't want it on the worksheet by filtering it from the pivot fields list.

Comment: Autofilter and then copy paste?

Comment: @mmarie Hi Marie- I think that's a good idea but the True/False change by pressing a form control - so I'm not sure ...

Answer (score 2):

Lots of options:

- Array formula, entered with Ctrl+Shift+Enter (copy down, it will turn to zero once you're out of values)

  `=LARGE(IF($B$1:$B$11=TRUE,$A$1:$A$11,0),ROW())`
- Pivot table, as suggested by mmarie
- Autofilter as suggested by Sid Rout

Comment: Thank you - I like the idea of an array (haven't used them much) -- When I use your LARGE formula I get a "#NUM!" error... Just to clarify - the B1:B11 references the True/False column, the A1:A11 references the date variable column - correct? and then inside ROW()) - do I need to enter any range value?  Thanks!

Comment: You'll get the #num error once the row() returns a number greater than the number of rows in your range. Row() will work if you start the formula in row 1, if you start in row n, use `row()+1-n` instead of `row()`.